# How to free the GPU memory in JCuda as free function provided in JCuda is not releasing the GPU memory in real time applications?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, jcuda

```
CUdeviceptr deviceInputA = new CUdeviceptr();
cuMemAlloc(deviceInputA, size * Sizeof.DOUBLE);
cuMemcpyHtoD(deviceInputA, Pointer.to(inputfingerprint), size * Sizeof.DOUBLE);

cuMemFree(deviceInputA);
```

> Here cuMemFree is not releasing the GPU memory .

Answer (score 1):

Finally , this problem is resolved . I had a 2D output array and was not deallocating the inner pointers of the array on the GPU . Hence GPU memory was not being released .
After deallocation , it is releasing the GPU memory .
cuMemFree is working absolutely fine in JCuda .